# Why are inline-block elements not displayed correctly in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code:

```
<div style='width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;'>
  <div style='display: inline-block; width: 70px; border: 1px solid green;'>
    asdfasdf<br />asdf
  </div>
  <div style='display: inline-block; width: 70px; border: 1px solid green;'>
    asdfasdf<br />were
  </div>
</div>
```

This displays just fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in Internet Explorer 8, it does not. They have layout, so that isn't the problem, and the widths are small enough that it fits on one line.

If I use `<span>`s instead, it does work; however, I would really like to know why `<div>`s don't work in IE.

Comment: Does your document have a doctype declaration?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work?" What is your desired effect?

Comment: Ahhh ok well I had HTML 4 declared since its an extremely old page instead of XHTML or HTML5

Comment: HTML5 doctype degrades gracefully in older browsers. Your example looks the same in chrome latest and ie8.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The old versions of IE don't understand the `inline-block` for block-level elements.

The reason why `inline-block` works for inline elements is because they did it so it triggers `hasLayout`. And the has layout for inline elements works *exactly* like an `inline-block`.

So, to make `inline-block` work with block-level elements, make them inline and somehow trigger the `hasLayout`, like, using `zoom: 1`.

So, for you code, there are two ways: change `div`s to `span`s, or add inline hacks (or move the code to external stylesheets and use conditional comments). The version with inline hacks would look like this:

```
<div style='width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;'>
  <div style='display: inline-block; width: 70px; border: 1px solid green;*display:inline;zoom:1;'>
    asdfasdf<br />asdf
  </div>
  <div style='display: inline-block; width: 70px; border: 1px solid green;*display:inline;zoom:1;'>
    asdfasdf<br />were
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

`display: inline-block;
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;`

you can add inline-block for other browser but for IE you can add style with *. it only works in ie

Answer (score 2):

Changing the doc type worked for IE

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

IE < 8 cannot switch elements that are `block` by default to `inline-block` elements. No matter how hard you try, they will always remain `block` unless you use `float` IIRC.

In your example it seems that you do not need to use a `<div>`. If this is the case, why not use a `<span>` or an element that is `inline` by default. Otherwise,  `floating` is the answer.

Comment: This is not true. IE8 understands _inline-block_ display mode just fine. But IE7 is completely unaware of that mode. Though you can emulate _inline-block_ behaviour by setting display to _inline_ and forcing layout for that element (with _zoom_ property, for instance).

Comment: So it does. IE8 seems to work properly with `inline-block` I shall update my answer.

Comment: IE8 works well with inline-block until you start hiding/showing elements inside the inline-block that would cause the parent containers to grow or shrink.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style type="text/css">
.one {
  width: 200px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.two {
  display: -moz-inline-box; 
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 70px; 
  border: 1px solid green;
}
* html .two {
  display: inline;
}
* + html .two {
  display: inline;
}
</style>
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    asdfasdf<br />asdf
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    asdfasdf<br />were
  </div>
</div>
```